# Disable select option based on another select option

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have 2 select:

```
<select id="select_1" name="tipo_carta">
 <option value="1">90gr</option>
 <option value="2">150gr</option>
 <option value="3">270gr</option>
</select>

<select id="select_2" name="stampa">
 <option value="0">Fronte</option>
 <option value="1">Fronte e Retro</option>
</select>
```

I would disable option "Fronte e Retro" (from select_2) when I select option "270gr" (from select_1)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have just seen by looking at your source code that you are not using jQuery but mootools -> I will re-flag this question but thus the answers there are not correct since we were all assuming you were using jQuery!

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie I'd be happy to add a proper [tag:mootools] solution, but how did you see that from this small bit of HTML?

Comment: Also, I just removed 'jquery' from the title - was kind of confusing after the retag  ;)

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes I have seen this from the site he provided to us in the comment of the solutions below... Your mootools solution is far better than mine! :)

Comment: Yeah I saw his site linked elsewhere later hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the other answers aren't exactly 'concise', and mostly jQuery based, I [implemented a 2 liner Mootools solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/VbvYC/):

```
$('select_1').addEvent('change', function(e) {
    $$('#select_2 option[value=1]').set('disabled',e.target.value == 3);
});
```

Put it in your `domready` or wherever you are initializing UI events.

For extremely old Mootools versions you'll have to be a bit more verbose:

```
$('select_1').addEvent('change', function(e) {
    $$('#select_2 option[value=1]').each(function(el){ el.disabled = (e.target.value == 3);});
});
```

Comment: finally, somebody with sense :) I'd change $$ for `document.getElement()` for performance purposes, no need to have a collection and iterator

Comment: Well in case like this performance isn't realistically an issue, so I went for both maximum readibility and brevity :)

Comment: sure but I hate leaving ineffective code around, it's lazy and means you don't always think things through - easy to then do the same when performance DOES matter and get into trouble.

Comment: I have tried but dosen't work...here you can test: [link]http://www.sgagrafica.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage_new.tpl&product_id=40&category_id=7&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=123&vmcchk=1&Itemid=118

Comment: You can see from the link in my post the code works, you are having another problem. If you open your developer console you'll see a glaring *"Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5*" error that's causing all other Javascript on the page not to work.

Comment: Sorry but I can't found the Error causing issue...can you help me? error is only one or there are more than one error?

Comment: Now with CHROME i see "Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5" but I see that if hi delete your code (that you have answered) I have not this error on CHROME...where is the problem?

Comment: I have this Error:
Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5
Element.extend.setProperty
Element.extend.set
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)

Comment: Your website include Mootools v1.12, which is not only several years old, but also fundamentally incompatible with 1.4 and later on a lot of points. You should definitely upgrade this - my code was written for 1.4.5 as you can see in the Fiddle. Can't guarantee it won't break other things in the site though.

Comment: I've added a sample that should also work in 1.12 if you can't upgrade for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('#select_1').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 3){
    $('#select_2').find('option:eq(1)').prop('disabled',true);
  }else{
     $('#select_2').find('option:eq(1)').prop('disabled',false);
  }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/RaNQP/1/)

Comment: I have tried but dosen't works..you can check here: [link]http://www.sgagrafica.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage_new.tpl&product_id=40&category_id=7&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=123 
select are: "select_20" and "select_11"

Comment: @bipen : this is not the blocking point... this add another event but the code with the `change` event has the `#` character in the selector (check l. 378)...

Comment: no i meant... our code is fine.... i went through is view source and found he has incorrect selector in his other codes.. so that is breaking the script and our code is not working..check line 337,347 ..so on..

Comment: @bipen yes I have seen this, but the other point is blocking too... But I have re-read the code, and I discover that the OP use mootools but not jquery!!! So that code from l. 337 and so on works correctly with mootools but this is the code that we propose that don't work then...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below

```
$('#select_1').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == '3') {
        $("#select_2 option:contains('Fronte e Retro')").attr({disabled:true});
    } else {
       $("#select_2 option:contains('Fronte e Retro')").attr({disabled:false});
    }
```

});

Comment: You should use `prop()` instead of `attr()` here

Comment: and `option[value=1]` rather than inspecting content

Comment: I have tried but dosen't works. I call these select also to do other things. You can se here http://www.sgagrafica.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage_new.tpl&product_id=40&category_id=7&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=123

Comment: @monak83 : this is because you call the `change` (l. 378) event before adding the `select` (l. 694) to the page... You have 2 options : either you call your script at the bottom of your page, or you embed it in the `$(document).ready` call...

Comment: Then use $('#select_1').live('change',function() {

Comment: @Samuel Caillerie sorry but I'm a newbie...can you tell me step by step what I should do? I have tried to add $('#select_1').live('change',function() { like suggest @ Manish Jangir but dosen't works.

Comment: @monak83 : the easiest option is to create a new `script` block at the end of your page (or use the one at l. 1260...) and to put the block `$('#select_20').change(...)` on l. 378 in this `script` block.

Comment: @ManishJangir sorry...i wich way? What I should do? i'm dummy with jquery...sorry

Comment: You have to put a script tag in your footer or anywhere else as Samuel Caillerie said

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie thanks a lot for your goldent time!
I think is better to embed it in the $(document).ready call so i have all script code in a unique files. To do this...what I should do?